# USB C 3.1 CC Connections

Tags: usb-c

I have two devices A acting as (UFP) and B (UFP or DFP). Device A supplies 3.3V to device B on SBU1 and SUB2 pins of USB C 3.1.

I am not using Vbus to supply power to Device B. SuperSpeed pins of USB C 3.1 are not used as superspeed signals but they are just used for transferring signals from B to A.

My question is can I achieve transmission of signals by using Device A as UFP and Device B also as UFP? Basically can I pull down the CC pins of device A and B?

Note: I am using HD3SS460 MUX on Device A.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it is possible. If you connect the CC lines of the products to some relays, you can choose to connect them to high/low depending on the configuration.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/310526)